# How to decrypt an encrypted file by passing the "gpg passphrase" in the command using PHP?

Tags: php, encryption, gnupg, secret-key, passphrase

I would like to know how can i decrypt a file by passing the passphrase/secret key in the command line.

I tried using this, but its still giving me a prompt to enter the passphrase.

echo shell_exec("echo $passphrase | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 -o $unencrypted_file -d $encrypted_file");

My goal is to created a program in PHP that can decrypt the files automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use the [php functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gnupg.php) instead of forking gpg

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what approach the gpg developers were using to prevent that. But as an alternative you can use this PHP module: http://pecl.php.net/package/gnupg to handle the decryption. See also http://php.net/gnupg

Answer (score 0):

```
gpg --passphrase-file $file
```

man gpg says : "Read the passphrase from file **file**. Only the first line will be read from file **file**. This can only be used if only one passphrase is supplied. Obviously, a passphrase stored in a file    is of questionable security if other users can read this file. Don't use this option if you can avoid it."

Comment: A slightly safer variation on this would be to set the caching period for gpg-agent to something ridiculous (like a month or more; it needs to be set in number of seconds) and then enter the passphrase monthly (or whetever period) plus after each reboot.  At least then gpg-agent and pinentry will protect the passphrase as they do normally (though an unattended system that is compromised will be vulnerable to RAM attacks to obtain the passphrase or decrypted secret key data).